# Excel ignoring a leading code(45) hyphen when sorting text

Tags: excel-2013

When I sort the following:
-Dandy
Dazzle 
Daddy 
_Date

I get:
_Date
Daddy 
-Dandy 
Dazzle

And not, as expected:
_Date 
-Dandy 
Daddy 
Dazzle

There seems to be a lot online about dealing with hyphens in alphanumeric text. Usually the solution is to strip the hyphen to get a proper sort, but my problem is that I WANT Excel to recognise the leading dash.

All text is preceded by a ' in cell.

The dash is code(45)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Any more code to show? I'm honestly a bit confused

Comment: No code, straightforward worksheet sort. I am running it from VBA but the result is the same from VBA or the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

The 'best' solution may be to write your own code to order as you wish, but I think what you want can be achieved with formulae, assuming:

- Only Code(45) is to be given priority over alphabetic characters
- Your data will nowhere include three `a` together

Your data is highlighted yellow in the image and the required output highlighted blue. I added some extra input:

[image: SO27955024 example]

The formula in B1 (copied down to suit) is:

```
 =IF(LEFT(A1)="-",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,MID(A1,2,1),MID(A1,2,1)&"aaa"),"-",""),A1)
```

ColumnD is a copy of ColumnB inserted with Paste Special, Values and Sorted A-Z.

The formula in F1, copied down to suit, is:

```
=IF(MID(D1,2,3)="aaa","-"&LEFT(D1)&MID(D1,4,LEN(D1)),D1)
```